# Phing does just the default target

Tags: php, jenkins, phing

I have a problem with Phing. He only does the default job. Has anyone encountered such behavior? The environment works on Windows 10.
Thank you for your help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="Test" default="start">
    <!-- ============================================  -->
    <!-- Target: start                                 -->
    <!-- ============================================  -->
    <target name="start">
        <echo msg="Start build" />
    </target>
    <!-- ============================================  -->
    <!-- Target: prepareDirectory                      -->
    <!-- ============================================  -->
    <target name="prepareDirectory" depends="start">
        <echo msg="Making directory build ./build" />
        <mkdir dir="./build" />
        <echo msg="Making directory install ./install" />
        <mkdir dir="./install" />       
    </target>       
    <!-- ============================================  -->
    <!-- Target: build                                 -->
    <!-- ============================================  -->
    <target name="build" depends="prepareDirectory">
        <echo msg="Copying files to build directory..." />

        <echo msg="Copying ./about.php to ./build directory..." />
        <copy file="./about.php" tofile="./build/about.php" />

        <echo msg="Copying ./browsers.php to ./build directory..." />
        <copy file="./browsers.php" tofile="./build/browsers.php" />

        <echo msg="Copying ./contact.php to ./build directory..." />
        <copy file="./contact.php" tofile="./build/contact.php" />
    </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set dependencies the other way around. Your target "start" does not trigger any other targets with your current code.

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="Test" default="build">
    <!-- ============================================  -->
    <!-- Target: start                                 -->
    <!-- ============================================  -->
    <target name="start">
        <echo msg="Start build" />
    </target>
    <!-- ============================================  -->
    <!-- Target: prepareDirectory                      -->
    <!-- ============================================  -->
    <target name="prepareDirectory" depends="start">
        <echo msg="Making directory build ./build" />
        <mkdir dir="./build" />
        <echo msg="Making directory install ./install" />
        <mkdir dir="./install" />       
    </target>       
    <!-- ============================================  -->
    <!-- Target: build                                 -->
    <!-- ============================================  -->
    <target name="build" depends="prepareDirectory">
        <echo msg="Copying files to build directory..." />

        <echo msg="Copying ./about.php to ./build directory..." />
        <copy file="./about.php" tofile="./build/about.php" />

        <echo msg="Copying ./browsers.php to ./build directory..." />
        <copy file="./browsers.php" tofile="./build/browsers.php" />

        <echo msg="Copying ./contact.php to ./build directory..." />
        <copy file="./contact.php" tofile="./build/contact.php" />
    </target>
</project>
```

The execution order will be: **start -> prepareDirectory -> build**

Hope that works!

Comment: It works. Thank you for your help. I already understand how the default target works.

Comment: I'm sorry for that. I'm new to 'StackOverflow'. I do not know all the mechanisms yet.

Comment: gosh, should really opt to remove these ugly and senseless comments. my eyes are bleeding :D but seriously, Robert C. Martins states that a comment that just states what you can read 1 line below is just ... trash